# Enable access-based enumeration adminshare on Windows 2012

Tags: windows

I can't find this option for adminshare on windows 2012 ( I can enable on folder) . I don't want to change file and folder structure so please help me to enable this function.

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to enable ABE for an administrative share...?

Comment: It's my customer requirement. 

The folder structure is :

E:\Accounting
E:\HR
E:\GA
E:\IT
E:\Private
E:\Public.

Normally I can enable ABE on E$ ( windows server 2008 ) so ( example : IT staff can see only IT folder and Public folder ).

If I change folder structure like this:

E:\Share\Accounting
E:\Share\HR

It may break file's link content inside each current folder.

Comment: This is so so wrong. If I could underline the word 'never' in the answer below I would do so repeatedly.

Answer (score 3):

[Built-In Administrative Shares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share), as the name already implies, are dedicated for administrative purposes only. Your customers should be NEVER accessing the data via that kind of method. This is wrong on many levels, one of them being the fact that the shares are only available for the users belonging to Administrators (unless you mess up with values under *HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\DefaultSecurity*) and I do not see why would you want to have all users accessing the shares to have administrative permissions on the server itself.

Therefore, this is the limitation and the option to configure ABE settings for these shares is not presented in Server Manager, nor these shares have any configurable options in registry.

If you want to make this work in your current structure, just share the whole drive (**E:\**) (which is still [not considered a good practice](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-share-the-root-of-a-drive), but it is much better than using administrative shares) as a regular share (e.g **E**), so the users could access everything via **\\server\E** (*\\server\E\HR*, *\\server\E\GA* etc.).

The best approach, still, would be to have separate shared folders (or at least one) in the root of the drive.